# How to load django model rows in a list?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model that I am basically querying on keypress using ajax to find possible matches cause I am avoiding duplicated rows.

Now my question is how can I copy all the rows from a django model and query on it rather than hitting the database every time the user presses a key because I do not think this is a good idea and please correct me if I am wrong.

What are the consequences of hitting a database on keypress?

Comment: You could use something like django cacheops to automatically cache certain querysets, this will use redis, but its not too hard to set up https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.